# How can I fix ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'.) error in spyder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder

I have installed spyder and python version 3.9.2
sklearn package is installed
but when I write " from sklearn.datasets import load_iris"
I find ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'.
How can I fix this problem?

when I start spyder in the kernel is written "Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]"
but I have python 3.9.2

Comment: Can you do "import sklearn"? If not, maybe you installed it in the wrong environment. Inspect the installed packages.

Comment: no. I find the same error when I write import skelearn.how can I inspect the installed package?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you cannot import the package means you did not install it correctly or did not install it in the right environment.

You can check which interpreter is running by using

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

You can check which environment a `pip` instance refers to by running

`$ pip --version`

Make sure to install the package in the right environment.

You can also call `pip` as a python module. For example, you can list available packages with `$ python -m pip list`.

Comment: Please consider adding some details on what the problem was and how you solved it. Otherwise, this question becomes useless to others who have the same problem in the future. Also, please accept my answer if you found it helpful or write your own answer and accept that. This is to remove this question from "not yet solved" lists.